# Lets have some consistency for the Beta Layout of the website

Tags: bug, design

I was reviewing the layout of the website and seems like it isn't consistent over pages, if we take a look at the Home page... We have `border-bottom` ALMOST overlying the main `border` of the menu.

[image]

---

Now if we move on to our Profile page, the *borders* are way above the main `border`

[image]

So is this intentional? If yes than it doesn't look good to me as far as UI is concerned, and should considered to be changed.

Comment: #tabs, #tabs a {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #tabs a {
        line-height: 26px;
    }